# How to restore deleted file which got deleted on branch merge?

Tags: git, github

I had a file, for example `~/project/config/myconfig.yml` and it was ignored by the git in the `.gitignore`

But now, when I have merged `master`, the file got lost, deleted, and as it was never pushed to the git (as it was ignored), I can't find it in the logs.

How to restore that `myconfig.yml` file?

Comment: So the file was never tracked by git? If this is the case I do not think you can restore it...

Comment: Yes, has never been tracked by git, unfortunately

Comment: @TM90 is right, but I'm just wondering how you lost a file ignored by .gitignore during a merge.

Comment: Yes it cannot be deleted during a merge when it is not tracked...

Comment: Because the mentioned file has been removed from the `.gitignore` in the updated version of the branch, and that is why it got deleted once I have pulled the updated branch

Comment: Plus 1 for the first comment :) that will be the answer in this case then

Comment: That still wouldn't delete the file @Aleks

Comment: hmm @bitoiu. In that case, perhaps it is possible that I have switched to some other branch after the merge. Maybe that caused the file to be deleted, as that other branch didn't have it in git ignore as well ?

Comment: that would not delete the file as well :)

Comment: How did you merge the two branches? Did you use git stash -u at some point?

Comment: @bitoiu then I don't know :) I have done: `git checkout master`, `git pull`, `git checkout my_branch`, `git merge master`, and the file is gone :) `master` branch has removed my file from `.gitignore`. Maybe that was the case?

Comment: git simply will not stomp on uncommitted content without an explicit order.    It's hardnosed enough about this that newcomers complain. If it deleted a file without you asking it to then it was tracked and committed at the time.

Answer (score 2):

1. If the file was never tracked you cannot restore it!
2. But the main question here is what happended?

A merge cannot delete a file which is not tracked, even if the .gitignore is changed.

My guess is that you may used **git stash -a** or **git stash --all** at some point.

I would recommand you to try **git stash pop** which may restore previous stashed files.

This last part is just a guess but it should be given a try.

Comment: I agree, the main question is how it happened. All I did was: `git checkout master`, `git pull`, `git checkout my_branch`, `git merge master`, and the file is gone :) No fancy commands :)

Comment: For the trouble I will mark it as answered - as you are right, seems like I am not being able to restore it. I will wait till tomorrow , maybe someone else has some solution